# How to change core's default services

Tags: 8, symfony-services

Dependency Injection is added to core, but there's no documentation to tell how developer can alter the default services. For example, I would like to change cache.bootstrap class to APC Caching.

Comment: Oh but [there is](https://drupal.org/node/2026959) :)

Comment: Aw, my fault. I am sorry.

Comment: No need to apologise, unless you know it's done using compiler passes I think that would be pretty hard to find. If you get a chance please do add an answer with the code you end up using, I'm sure it will be very useful to future visitors. If not I'll try to remember to come back and add something generic in

Comment: It's no longer done using compiler passes.

Comment: The answer by @chx is perfect, but note that your example is a special case. I suggest you open a separate question on how to provide a different cache backend and we can answer that in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at [LanguageTestServiceProvider](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!language!tests!language_test!lib!Drupal!language_test!LanguageTestServiceProvider.php/class/LanguageTestServiceProvider/8) to see how alterations are made. Or I can offer my class:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\mongodb;

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceModifierInterface;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

/**
 * MongoDB service provider. Registers Mongo-related services.
 */
class MongodbServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface, ServiceModifierInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function register(ContainerBuilder $container) {
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    foreach ($container->findTaggedServiceIds('mongodb.override') as $id => $attribute) {
      $container->setDefinition(substr($id, 8), $container->getDefinition($id));
    }
  }

}
```

Basically, in `alter` you need to use the `getDefinition` method, do something with the [definition](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Definition.html) and then use the `setDefinition` method to put it back.

and then here's the relevant parts of mongodb.services.yml:

```
services:
  mongodb.flood:
    class: Drupal\mongodb\Flood\MongoDBBackend
    arguments: ['@mongo', '@request']
    tags:
      - { name: mongodb.override }
```

Comment: Just wanted to mention it looks like you don't need to use `setDefintion()` if you've used `getDefinition()` - you can just update the definition.